# How to link textbox to a specific cell on specific sheet in Excel?

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub RankCombo_Change()
Dim Val As String

Val = Me.RankCombo.Value
 [L15].Value = Val
 
End Sub
```

I'm trying to get this textbox/dropdown to link to L15 on Sheet 1, which is not active sheet and is hidden. I tried [sheet1.L15] but I can't find the wording for it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the Range reference.

```
Private Sub RankCombo_Change()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L15").Value = Me.RankCombo.Value
 
End Sub
```

ThisWorkbook is only needed if you are working with multiple workbooks.

You should change your worksheet codenames and refer to them by there codename.  See [Wise Owl Tutorials: Refer to Sheets by CodeName](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s112/microsoft-excel-vba-worksheet-sheet-name-codename.htm)

Comment: How would I apply specific cell (L15) in here? thank you in advance!

Comment: Still getting Run-time Error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: Silly me, I named it the sheet name and not Sheet1, thanks